# How do you do this in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to design sleek magnifying glass effects like these?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2489/how-to-design-sleek-magnifying-glass-effects-like-these)

I've seen this done many times, and I'm wondering how to do it.

[image: Example]

If someone could point me to a tutorial on how to do the magnifying glass thing, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: In what context do you need to do this? Do you already have an image that you want to "magnify" or are you going to start from scratch?

Comment: I just want the a tutorial on how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why or how the same question got asked twice in 10 days, but here you go: [How to design sleek magnifying glass effects like these?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2489/how-to-design-sleek-magnifying-glass-effects-like-these/2490#2490)

Matthew gave an adequate answer, but didn't mention how to do the layer effects.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open an image.
2. Select all and Copy it.
3. Create a new layer and Paste the copy.
4. Shrink the first layer to the appropriate size.
5. Use a shape tool (I'm away from my PS install at the moment so forgive my imprecision) to draw a circle around the area of interest in the second layer.
6. Use the Magic Wand to select everything outside of the circle and delete it.
7. Move the second layer around so that the circled area is over the appropriate part of the first layer.
8. Resize the canvas to fit the image.

Comment: I would change (6) to "apply a layer mask to hide everything outside the circle." This way, you do not destroy your work from previous steps, and you can alter the size of the circle or even move the magnified section later.

Comment: Steps 5 and 6 could be replaced by making a selection with _Elliptical Marquee Tool_ and _Layer->Layer Mask->Reveal Selection_. As with horatio's comment, it would give a bit more tweakability afterwards.